# Unexpected Eof exception when req.body from nodejs is sent to a springboot rest controller

Tags: java, node.js, spring-restcontroller, express-validator

I have a nodejs application which receives input in the form of a json from frontend.

Input request

```
{
"name":"tina",
"address":{
"doorNo":"54",
"street":"Haddows"
},
"age":"12"
}
```

I use express and express validator ->{body,validationresult} to validate the json.

**In the request the "address" is optional.
If the frontend does not pass the address, then i expect the request to be in the below format:**

```
{ "name":"tina","age": "12"}
```

Controller.js

```
const resultant = async 
function(req, res) {
try{
console.log(JSON.stringfy(req.body));
const res  app.post( 
"http://localhost:8080/details",
req.body,req.headers);
} catch(error){
console.log("error is 
:"+error.toString())
}
}
```

RestControllerApp.java

```
public class RestControllerApp {
@RestController
RequestMapping(value = "/details", 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> 
persist(@RequestBody PersonDTO 
person) {
if (personSvc.isValid(person)) { 
personRepo.persist(person);
return ResponseEntity. 
status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
} 
}
```

When the request reaches the restcontrollerapp.java, i get the below error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]) at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 8001] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportInvalidEOF(ParserMinimalBase.java:618) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._handleEOF(ParserBase.java:485) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._eofAsNextChar(ParserBase.java:497) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2340) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser
```

From the nodejs controller.js, i get the below in console.log(JSON.stringfy(req.body)):

```
{
"name":"tina",
"address":{
"doorNo":"",
"street":""
},
"age":"12"
}
```

When i paste the above json in postman and directly hit the java controller, **the flow works without showing the jsonexception.**

Can anyone please help me out to solve this tricky issue?

A Million thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need both the triple-back-quote AND 4 spaces indentation, either one will do.  Please correct the code indentation.

Comment: content-type: application/json should be the issue i assume